# how to create an action for a clicked image from imageviewanimation

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

### [SOLVED - SEE THE ANSWER]

i want to have three images grouping as animation, and i can be able to click any of these three images to define an action. In the other words, i'd like to know the ways to create separate action/ event for each image in the animation

that will be great if you know there's a way to do with UIButton instead of UIImageview

here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load images
    NSArray *imageNames = @[@"hello.png",@"bye.png",@"helloagain.png"];

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    // Normal Animation
    UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 95, 86, 90)];
    animationImageView.animationImages = images;
    animationImageView.animationDuration = 1.5;

    [self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
    [animationImageView startAnimating];
    animationImageView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bannerTapped:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [animationImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}

- (void)bannerTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {   
    //action here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use an animating image view to do this, since you can't get the image from the image view when you click on it. Instead, use a timer to switch the images. Something like this should work,

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *images;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImageView *animationImageView;
@end

@implementation ViewController {
    NSInteger counter;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *imageNames = @[@"hello.png",@"bye.png",@"helloagain.png"];

    self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
        [self.images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    self.animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 95, 86, 90)];
    self.animationImageView.image = self.images[0];
    [self.view addSubview:self.animationImageView];
    self.animationImageView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bannerTapped:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.animationImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void)changeImage:(NSTimer *) timer {
    if (counter == self.images.count - 1 ) {
        counter = 0;
    }else {
        counter ++;
    }
    self.animationImageView.image = self.images[counter];
}

- (void)bannerTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIImage *img = self.animationImageView.image;
    NSInteger indx = [self.images indexOfObject:img];
    NSLog(@"The index is: %ld", indx);
    // use indx value in a switch statement or if-else block to choose your action
}
```

**After Edit**

If you want different times between images, I would use a different approach. Instead of using a timer, just call the following method to start the animation,

```
-(void)changeImage {
    if (counter == self.images.count - 1 ) {
        counter = 0;
    }else {
        counter ++;
    }
    self.animationImageView.image = self.images[counter];

    if (counter == 1) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(changeImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
    }else{
        [self performSelector:@selector(changeImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
    }
}
```

This would give you a 2 second delay between the 2nd and 3rd image, but 1 second between the others.

Comment: i got one more question and i hope you could answer it. do you know how to set a different interval between the second pic and third pic? @rdelmar

Comment: @katie I've edited my answer to show a different way that would work better with different times between images.

Comment: so i will just need to use my original method?

Comment: @katie What original method? From your question? No, you use the code I posted in my edit. Just delete the NSTimer line, and change the changeImage method to the one in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

My proposed hacky solution assuming you know number of images, and animation time.

1. Schedule a timer for imageCount/animationTime milliseconds.
 2. In the timer's callback, increment the above property on the UIImageView
 3. In `-bannerTapped` use that index to decide what event to throw corresponding to the image currently being animated.

```
-(void)setup {

    // Load images
    NSArray *imageNames = @[@"happy",@"sad",@"popeye_village"];

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    // Normal Animation
    imageview.frame = CGRectMake(60, 95, 86, 90);
    imageview.animationImages = images;
    imageview.animationDuration = 6;

    [imageview startAnimating];
    imageview.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bannerTapped:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [imageview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:((double)imageview.animationDuration / images.count)
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateAnimatingImage)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];


}

- (void)bannerTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Clicked on Image index %li", imageview.indexOfAnimatingImage] message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

-(void)updateAnimatingImage
{
    imageview.indexOfAnimatingImage = ++imageview.indexOfAnimatingImage % (imageview.animationImages.count);
    NSLog(@"index currently showing is %li",imageview.indexOfAnimatingImage);
}
```

While very similar to the above solution, this still uses UIImageView's animationImages.
[Here](https://github.com/lordvisionz/NSTIMER-IMAGE-ANIMATION-) is my fork of your project in case you want to play with a working solution.

Comment: So do I need to use nstimer? Can you please provide the code I'm really new and couldn't find any related answer that I'm looking for :(

Comment: @katie please read [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/). You always learn more this way.

Comment: I read it all before I asked this question and I still don't understand another easier tutorial?

Comment: @katie do you know categories and extensions in objective-c?

Comment: you don't have to use them. Its just cleaner that way. Just use a counter instead of the category I mentioned. Update the counter from the NSTimer callback method. Check for the counter from `-bannerTapped`. Does that sound doable?

Comment: do i still need to add "interface UIImageView(KTImageView)

property (readwrite) NSUInteger indexOfAnimatingImage;

end"
 then?

Comment: @katie no. That is the category class. Just add the timer, the callback, a counter.

Comment: so how can i create action for the image i click in animation?

Comment: @katie using the counter I mentioned, you just say if (clickedImage == 0) clickImage1(); if(clickedImage == 1)clickImage2(); and so on. This problem is a great example for categories. If you create your project and put it up on github I will implement my proposed solution for you.

Comment: I've tried my best :/ here is my project https://www.sendspace.com/file/g30zng. I've tried uploading to github twice but the Xcode project has gone empty.

Comment: @katie Check out my updated solution. I also have a solution on github for it